# Rails 4 partial with form not rendering

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, partial

I have partial file `_form.erb.html`:

```
<p>Name: </p><%= f.text_field :name %>
<p>Description: </p><%= f.text_field :description %>
<p>Price: </p><%= f.text_field :price %>
<p>Weight: </p><%= f.text_field :weight %>
```

and view file `items/new.html.erb`:

```
<h1>New item</h1>
<%= form_for @item do |f| %>
    <% render partial: 'form', locals: { :f => f} %>
    <p><%= f.submit 'Create' %></p>
<% end %>
```

But, when I go to the 0.0.0.0:3000/items/new I see a page without a form and no errors displayed. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You are missing the `=`. It should be `<%= render partial: 'form', locals: { :f => f} %>`

Comment: Damn, this is so stupid mistype! Thank you a lot!

Comment: @Андрей Ярощук, please accept AbM's response if you accept the solution

Comment: @AbM needs to type it in as an answer first :)

Comment: @papirtiger yes, i realized this just now

Comment: @AbM please add this as a answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the `=`. It should be `<%= render partial: 'form', locals: { :f => f} %>`